# How can I change multiple values in one column that contain specific substring in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe

I have a pandas DataFrame where a column contains several strings:

```
sample_df = 
    cars
0   BMW
1   Honda
2   Porshe
3   BMWLuxury
4   TeslaLuxury
5   Ford
6   Ferrari
7   PorsheLuxury
```

I would like to change the value in column "cars" that contains substring "Luxury" with 1 and others with 0. How can I achieve this?

Comment: `sample_df["cars"].str.contains("Luxury")`

Comment: I am asking how to change values, I am not asking how to return values with substring "Luxury"

Comment: What is the expected output? What do you mean by "change values"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
df['cars'] = df['cars'].str.contains('Luxury').astype('int')
```

Output:

```
0    0
1    0
2    0
3    1
4    1
5    0
6    0
7    1
Name: cars, dtype: int32
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```py
df["cars"] = df["cars"].str.contains("Luxury").astype(int)
```

This outputs:

```py
   cars
0     0
1     0
2     0
3     1
4     1
5     0
6     0
7     1
```